# Is it possible for R to automatically make tables out of data you calculate (like summary, p-values)

Tags: database, dataframe

I'm doing my statistical analysis of my research project with R. That means, I have to create tables which I have to fill with values that are calculated with R, for example medians, means, IQRs, SDs, p-values. However, it may be sensitive to errors when I have to type all values from R into my table in Excel.
So, is there a way to automatically make tables out of data you calculate?